# How do I render a React component into the main App component/

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm in the process of moving my client-side code from jQuery to React. My (trimmed) main app looks like this

```
export const MyApp: FC = () => {
return <HashRouter>
    <SideNav {...data} />
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
    </Switch>
</HashRouter>
}
```

And inside several components I sometimes need to call functions that build React components. Such as

```
export async function openDialog(recordId?: number) {
const elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.style.display = 'contents';
ReactDOM.render(<ConfigProvider>
    <Modal
        visible recordId={recordId} 
        onCancel={() => {
            ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(elem);
            document.body.removeChild(elem);
        }} 
    />
</ConfigProvider>, elem);
document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

Problem is, that if in my `Modal` I have a react-router `Link`, then I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant failed You should not use Link outside a Router

Now, I could understand the error, because I'm rendering outside the context of the `MyApp`. My question is: How can I change my function so it does render into the same context of `MyApp`?

I was not able to find any such question or concept online (aside of rewriting my whole app to use a state for each window I need to open, which is not practical at the moment).

Thanks!

Comment: You could use [`Portals`](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)

Answer (score 0):

The components which use router links must be children of components rendered inside a router.

In your case, you only have `<Dashboard />` and `<SideNav />` rendered inside your router. Make sure that `<Modal / >` is rendered by `<Dashboard />`, `<SideNav />`, or a descendant of them.

You also manipulate DOM elements directly and this is not good practice with React. You could run into confusing bugs as React will not recognize changes to the DOM

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html

Comment: Hi. That precisely is my question. "How" do I call React.render (or similar) with a reference to MyApp so it renders it as a child of MyApp? Thanks!

Comment: What is currently rendering the modal?

Comment: My function 'openDialog'. Can I send it a reference to MyApp or something? So it renders within the same context?

Comment: @YisroelM.Olewski react portals exist for exactly this reason.

Comment: No libraries needed. Move your modal to its own component. Inside your dashboard, conditionally render your modal.

Comment: @im_baby not sure if the libraries comments refers to me, but portals are not a library, they are a part of react.

Comment: I'm checking out portals. But portals takes an `Element` as parent/container. I dont have an HTML DOM element in MyApp. MyApp is totally react. I need the modal to render as if it was inside Myapp.

Comment: @im_baby Obviously I "could" conditinally render inside my dashboard or whatever. That is the standard recommended way in React. But that would require a humongous code rewrite. For now I need a way to render a new component (modals) on the fly, but it should act as if it was rendered within MyApp. so that the rect router `Link`s will work correctly. Thanks!